# Using regex in Python to extract description of an app from Apple store html

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract description of an app from Apple store html. Description sits in-between

```
<p itemprop="description"> DESCRIPTION HERE </p>
```

Where description contains bunch of 
 symbols, words, spaces, etc.

Clearly html has lots of other text and tags, so it needs to be very precise for pattern matching.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML!

Use an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup!](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
>>> import bs4
>>> s = '<p itemprop="description"> DESCRIPTION HERE </p>'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
>>> soup.find("p", {"itemprop": "description"}).text
>>> u' DESCRIPTION HERE '
```

Or if you want to find all elements:

```
>>> [item.text for item in soup.find_all("p", {"itemprop": "description"})]
>>> [u' DESCRIPTION HERE ']
```

Comment: Assuming no import is possible, what would be the best approach to the problem?

Comment: Don't use BeautifulSoup either! Use bs4 https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: If the paragraph tag is regularly defined (probably using some template engine), then there is no harm in using regex to extract simple information from it. XPath is another alternative, assuming no importing allowed

Comment: @Adib the tools listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/markup.html) in the stdlib might work, and as cricket_007 says you can often get away with using regexs here (although I wouldn't recommend it)

Answer (score 2):

This will work with Apple store html:

```
(?<=<p\sitemprop="description">).*?(?=<\/p>)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP6cU2/1)

**Explanation:**
`(?<=…)`: Positive lookbehind [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wU2aD6/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`(?=…)`: Positive lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/cV6wG7/1)